# Update new Google sheet daily from orginal sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Not sure if this is an obvious answer.
I have a complete sheet with thousands of rows. What I need is for a new google sheet to update rows daily from the original sheet.
For example

- Day 1:     5 new rows imported from a spreadsheet
- Day 2:     5 new rows imported from a spreadsheet
- Day 3:     10 new rows imported from a spreadsheet
- Day 4:     15 new rows imported from a spreadsheet
- Day 5:     30 new rows imported from a spreadsheet

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is there a system how many rows should be imported each day?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the question would be the method to interact with *Google Sheet* with e.g. Python.

**1) Install 2 packages:**

```
python3 -m pip install --user gspread oauth2client
```

**2) Google Drive API (Google Cloud Platform)**

Credentials for Google Drive API:

1. Google Drive API > Enable > Create Credentials
2. Select Google Drive API > Web Server > Application Data > No I'm not using them
3. Any name > Editor > JSON
4. Download JSON credentials > Copy client_email > Share to this email in Google Sheets

**3. Google Sheets API (Google Cloud Platform)**

Google Sheets API > Enable

**4. gspread package**

*Get Methods:*

```
get_all_records()
row_values(row)
col_values(col)
cell(row, col).value
```

*Insert Methods:*

```
insert_row(array, rowNo)
delete_row(rowNo)
update_cell(rowNo, colNo, value)
```

I shall leave out the details of reading your local spreadsheet as details were not provided. To do this periodically, I suggest you consider running your Python script periodically with **Windows Task Scheduler**.

Reference: https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

p.s. I used to struggle with this while creating a [chatbot](https://github.com/tonyngmk/telegram-ntudb-bot) for a school project, so the following was what I had done previously.